# how to pattern match when downloading the file from sftp

Tags: shell, unix, curl, pattern-matching, sftp

Hi I am trying to write a curl command which downloads the latest file in the sftp connection. The files are in this format:
2019-11-01-samefilename-1572680144-timestamp.csv.gz

i am writing the curl command but i am not sure how to pattern matching for the timestamp as i dont know the exact value. Here's my curl command

`dateid=date  +%Y-%m-%d
curl -u user: --key id_rsa -k $sftppath/$dateid-samefilename-*.csv.gz -o "$destpath"`

But i think i cant use *. It is not working. How do i fix this?

Comment: What is sftppath ?

Comment: There are two issues: (1) curl does not support wild card (2) the wildcard expansion will not work locally.

As an alternative, consider doing listing on the folder ($sftppath), and then select the file that (best) matches the files that need to be downloaded

Comment: You know `sftp` can be called directly and do not need `curl`?  The `sftp` client command manages wildcards.

Comment: Are there multiple versions with different timestamp. Which one do you want to pick ?

Comment: There is only one file per day but i think i cant use pattern matching with curl..i will try some other way. Thanks

Comment: Assuming that you want to use curl (and not other tools like sftp, wget, lftp) - It will help if you can post sample output for `curl $sftppath`